# Compare Two table data and display not matched and match data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want Compare two tables.
TABLE 1 cODE :

```
  <table id='1'>
                <tr>
                                    <td>Account No1</td>                                                
                <tr>

                    <?php
                    $query="SELECT * FROM temp";

                    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                    {
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
                    {

                    ?>
                    <td ><?php echo $DESCRIPT=$row['ACCOUNTNO'];?></td>

                            <?php
                    }
                    }
                    ?>              
        </table>
```

Table 2 : code

```
        <table  id='2'>

                    <tr>
                        <td >Account No2</td>
                        <td>status</td>                         
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                <?php
                $query="SELECT * FROM temp2 ";

                if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {

                echo '<tr id="ite'.$row["ACCOUNTNO"].'">';


                ?>

                <td ><?php echo $DESCRIPT=$row['ACCOUNTNO'];?></td>
                         <td ><?php echo $DESCRIPT=$row['status'];?></td>

                <?php
                }

                }
                ?>      

   <input type="SUBMIT" class="btnStyle"    value="cHECK">
```

IT will display RESULT LIKE :

```
  --------------------------------------------
    Account no1  Account no2    Status
  --------------------------------------------
    000005      000005         L
    000007      000007         L
    8888888     0000089        A
                0000003        A
                9999999        L
```

No i want It will Display Red record if **account no 1 == acoount no2** and **status** is A  for account no1.

OR i want query that display **Acoountno1**  entire row red if **staus** is 'A' and **account no 1 == acoount no2**

if you want more info tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this updated code

```
<style>               
                .red_color, .red_color td{ color: red; } 

                </style>


  <table >

                    <tr>
                        <td >Account No1</td>
                         <td >Account No2</td>
                        <td>status</td>                         
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                <?php
                $query="select temp1.ACCOUNTNO as a1, temp2.ACCOUNTNO as a2, temp2.status from temp1 inner join temp2 on temp1.ACCOUNTNO = temp2.ACCOUNTNO where temp2.status in ('A','L')  ";

                if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {



                ?>
<tr id = "ite<?php echo $row["a1"]; ?>"  class = " <?php if($row['status'] == 'A') { echo "red_color" ; } ?>" >
                <td ><?php echo $row['a1'];?></td>
                  <td ><?php echo $row['a2'];?></td>
                         <td ><?php echo  $row['status'];?></td>

</tr>
                <?php
                }

                }
                ?>   
                </table>
```

Comment: But i want to display both Status A and L. if status is A then record in REd color

Comment: what do you mean RED color ? give example ?

Comment: Disaply all Records. and It means where status 'A' then that both table row is highlight by font-color or any other way